# Path with spaces in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Dummy.bat

```
set "EXECUTE_DIR=%2"

echo %EXECUTE_DIR%
```

on executing the command: `Dummy.bat "para1" C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`

I get output as:

```
C:\Program
```

but if i suround the parameters with double quotes: `Dummy.bat "para1" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"`

I get the desired output as:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
```

I want the double quotes to be optional. Is it possible?. What is that i am missing out?.

Thanks in advance. Please Help

Comment: AFAIK in every Microsoft utility that uses long filenames with spaces, they are always quoted.  Third party utilities use the same method - so you really should use a standard way of getting parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first argument from the list of the arguments, and put the result into a string:

```
@echo off
set s1=%*
set s2=%1
set s3=%s1:* =%
echo %s1%
echo %s2%
echo %s3%
```

Output:

```
c:\>Dummy.bat "para1" C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
"para1" C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
"para1"
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Answer (score 0):

As spaces are separators, if you want to use the standard argument handling and refer to your second parameter as %2, then there is no option but to use quotes to enclose a value that contains spaces.

An option is to code argument management. Determine that in your batch file, anything after some parameter number, in your case anything after the first parameter, will be handled as only one parameter, so you can write something like

```
@echo off

    set "_2="
:loop
    if defined _2 (set "_2=%_2% %2") else (set "_2=%2")
    shift
    if not "%~2"=="" goto :loop

    echo %_2%
```

this will concatenate all the parameters after the first one into a variable that you should use insted of the `%2` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set wholeline=%*
set "parm1=%~1"
set "parm2=%wholeline:* =%"
CALL set "parm2a=%%wholeline:*%1 =%%"
set parm

GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `set` a counter and take everything after the first element (`%1`).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "$l="
set "$c=0"
for %%a in (%*) do (
if !$c! geq 1 set $l=!$l! %%a
set /a $c+=1
)
echo !$l:~1!
```